# How to update scroll type?

Tags: monaco-editor

How can we update scroll type?

Based on this thread https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/859
below code doesn't work.

```
      scrollbar: {
          vertical: 'hidden',
      }
  });
```

Any other way or work-around is there?

Comment: fyi, I also see another thread where it is tagged as bug - https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2381.

Comment: I meant below doesn't work
editor.updateOptions({
        scrollbar: {
            vertical: 'hidden',
        }
    });